# unable to find servlet(.java) files converted from jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am using eclipse luna and tomcat version 7. I have written few jsp files and executing them on tomcat easily. I have read that jsps are converted into servlets at run time and you can locate them in tomcat/work/catalina/localhost/project name and further. My project name is quizilla and there exist a folder named quizilla-1.0-SNAPSHOT, but this folder is empty. What is the reason and where can i find those .java files. I have attached the screen shot of the folder as well[As I am in right directory in search of my java files, but the folder is empty. So what should i do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaEL6.png)

Answer (score 4):

You are using Tomcat from Eclipse, so the work directory is:

```
projectworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
```

or something like that (if you haven't changed the Server configuration via Eclipse).

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
<%=getClass().getResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class")%>
```

to one of your JSP pages to detect where Tomcat has generated the servlet.